# calculate this line integral

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals, line-integrals

this is my curve : 
$r(t)=(\cos{t},\sin{t}-1,2\cos{\frac{t}{2}})$ , $t=[0,3\pi]$

$r'(t)=(-\sin{t},\cos{t},-\sin{t})$

$||r'(t)||=\sqrt{\sin^2{t}+1}$

I have to calculate: $\int{(y+1)}ds$

So I have : $\int_{0}^{3\pi}\sin t\sqrt{\sin^2{t}+1}dt$

Is this right? If it is, can you help me figure out how to compute this integral?  I tried a lot of substitution but I can't get it any simpler.

Comment: You have a mistake in differentiation of $\cos\frac{t}{2}$ (you skipped the 1/2 in $\sin$).

Comment: @orion it’s $2\cos\frac{t}{2}$, so he doesn’t.

Comment: It should be $-\sin \frac{t}{2}$, not $-\sin t$. The half doesn't disappear from inside the trigonometric function after differentiation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$r(t)=(\cos{t},\sin{t}-1,2\cos{\frac{t}{2}})$ , $t=[0,3\pi]$

$r'(t)=(-\sin{t},\cos{t},-\sin{\frac{t}{2}})$ <- You forgot sin(t/2)

$||r'(t)||=\sqrt{\sin^2{\frac{t}{2}}+1}$

Calculate: $\int{(y+1)}ds$

-> $I = \int_{0}^{3\pi}\sin t\sqrt{\sin^2{\frac{t}{2}}+1}dt$

Apply subsitution $u = sin^2(\frac{t}{2}) + 1$

$du = \frac{\sin{t}}{2} dt$

$t = 0, u = 1. t = 3\pi,u = 2.$

$I = 2\int_{1}^{2}\sqrt{u}\textrm{ }du = \frac{4}{3}(2^\frac{3}{2}-1^\frac{3}{2})=\frac{4}{3}\times(2\sqrt{2}-1)=\frac{8\sqrt{2}-4}{3}$

Comment: why is It $du=\frac{sint}{2}$ ? how did you get $\frac{sint}{2}$?

Comment: $u = sin^2(\frac{t}{2}); du = 2sin(\frac{t}{2})cos(\frac{t}{2})\times \frac{1}{2}$ By Chain Rule. Simplify.